# How can I check is null in dax?

Tags: powerbi, null, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

Blank and Null are equal in DAX?
How can I just check ISNULL IN DAX? Not ISNULL OR ISBLANK CONDITION

Comment: There is no concept of Null in DAX, it uses BLANK instead. This should not be a problem - proper dimensional models never have nulls (they are replaced with default values in dimensions, for example, "Unknown", or "N/A").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use strictly equal for your comparisons ==

https://dax.guide/op/strictly-equal-to/